# Double Click Notification in Picture Control in CFromView?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a `CFormView` in which I have a Picture Control which is displaying OpenGL graphics. When the user double clicks in the OpenGL, the double click event is caught and some calculations performed in the OpenGL Class.
However, I would like to also know in my `CFormView` class that the button has been double clicked.

When I try to catch the double click in the View Class as follows:

```
*View::OnDblclkOpengl()
{
    MessageBox(_T("here"));
}
```

Nothing happens.

Can someone please tell me how I can catch the double click event in my View Class?

Comment: There isn't much information here other than `*View::OnDblclkOpengl(){...}`, I don't know what that means. Try overriding `PreTranslateMessage` see if it catches `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` message over the custom control.

Comment: show us your message map too

Comment: The SS_NOTIFY style is required to receive [STN_DBLCLK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760786(v=vs.85).aspx).  Have you set that on the control?

Comment: Hi how is SS_NOTIFY specified? I have under Picture Control/ Appearance/ Notify set as "True"- does this set SS_NOTIFY?

Comment: Yes, that sets the necessary style.